# Socket close may lead to connection CLOSE_WAIT in mono 4.0.2

Tags: c#, linux, sockets, mono

Recently i found a problem in socket, lead to CLOSE_WAIT, even already shutdown and close the socket.

1. i use a socket to listen connection, when a connection received, use the connection to receive data use BeginReceive, and then to accept for next connection.
2. when BeginReceive call back, use a delegate to process data async, and then BeginReceive next, and then the shutdown and close the connection.
3. the client connect the server socket, and then send data, and then close the socket in next 500 ~ 1000ms.
4. repeat this for some time, there find a lot of CLOSE_WAIT connection, but shutdown and close already been called.
5. Console output message such like : epoll_ctl(MOD): 17 File exists.

CentOS 6.2 x64
Mono 4.0.2

Is there some body meet the same case? or give me some advice. 
Thanks a lot.

Sample Code :

```
public class SocketTest
{
    private const int NET_LISTEN_BACKLOG                            = 128;

    private Socket m_serverSocket                                   = null;

    private Thread m_mainThread                                     = null;

    public int m_acceptNum                                          = 0;

    public SocketTest( )
    {
        m_mainThread = new Thread( new ThreadStart( MainProc ) );
        m_mainThread.Start( );
    }

    public void Startup( int port )
    {
        m_serverSocket = new Socket( AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );

        m_serverSocket.Bind( new IPEndPoint( IPAddress.Any, port ) );
        m_serverSocket.Listen( NET_LISTEN_BACKLOG );
        m_serverSocket.SetSocketOption( SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true );
        m_serverSocket.BeginAccept( new AsyncCallback( ServerAcceptCallback ), null );
    }

    private void ServerAcceptCallback( IAsyncResult ar )
    {
        try
        {
            //debug                                                 
            Interlocked.Increment( ref m_acceptNum );


            Socket socket           = m_serverSocket.EndAccept( ar );
            socket.NoDelay = true;

            STcpConnection con      = new STcpConnection( socket );

            con.RecvPakAsync( new SPackRecvCallback( TestProtocolPackRecvCallback ), null );

            m_serverSocket.BeginAccept( new AsyncCallback( ServerAcceptCallback ), null );
        }
        catch( Exception ex )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "ServerAcceptCallback : " + ex.ToString( ) );
        }
    }

    delegate void STestSendPackDelegate( STcpConnection conn );

    private void TestProtocolPackRecvCallback( STcpConnection conn, bool success, byte[] packData, string errMsg, object state )
    {
        try
        {
            if( !success )
            {
                conn.Close( );
                return;
            }

            STestSendPackDelegate dele = new STestSendPackDelegate( RetPack );
            dele.BeginInvoke( conn, null, null );

            conn.RecvPakAsync( new SPackRecvCallback( TestProtocolPackRecvCallback ), null );

            //here if close the socket, will cause CLOSE_WAIT.
            conn.Close( );
        }
        catch( Exception ex )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "TestProtocolPackRecvCallback : " + ex.ToString( ) );
        }
    }

    private void RetPack( STcpConnection conn )
    {
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( "Hello" );
        conn.TrySendDataAsync( data );
    }

    private void MainProc( )
    {
        try
        {
            while( true )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( string.Format( "-------------------------- {0} ---------------------------", DateTime.Now.ToString( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ) ) );
                Console.WriteLine( "m_acceptNum                       : " + m_acceptNum );

                Thread.Sleep( 5000 );
            }
        }
        catch( Exception ex )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( ex.ToString( ) );
        }
    }
}





public delegate void SPackRecvCallback( STcpConnection conn, bool success, byte[] packData, string errMsg, object state );

public class STcpConnection
{
    private Socket m_socket                                     = null;

    public IPAddress IPAddress
    {
        get { return ( ( IPEndPoint )m_socket.RemoteEndPoint ).Address; }
    }

    public int Port
    {
        get { return ( ( IPEndPoint )m_socket.RemoteEndPoint ).Port; }
    }

    public STcpConnection( Socket socket )
    {
        if( socket == null )
            throw new ArgumentNullException( );

        m_socket        = socket;
    }

    ......


    public void Close( )
    {
        try
        {
                try
                {
                    m_socket.Shutdown( SocketShutdown.Both );
                }
                catch( Exception ex )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine( "Close Exception : " + ex.ToString( ) );
                }

                m_socket.Close( );
            }
        }
        catch( Exception ex )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( ex.ToString( ) );
        }
    }

    private void OnPakRecvCallback( SPackRecvCallback cb, object state, bool success, byte[] msg, string errMsg )
    {
        try
        {
            if( cb != null )
            {
                cb( this, success, msg, errMsg, state );
            }
        }
        catch( Exception ex )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( ex.ToString( ) );
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is found in the real project, and the code is core to reproduce the problem. In the project we don't do such close, but in some case there will be CLOSE_WAIT.

Comment: socket implementation has received recently some refactoring, so test with Mono 4.2 first

Comment: thanks, i will try 4.2 first.

Comment: 4.2 Have fixed that for me.